# Looking for a list of rsync error outputs

Tags: rsync

I'm setting up at text filter for some of my routines. If I had a list of errors and other messages, as they are displayed in the output, this would make my filtered outputs a lot more versatile.

So far I have these patterns:
^ERROR:
^rsync error:
^skipping non-regular file

Is there documentation or notes on this anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll not find a nice, tidy answer to this question. I did a brute-force search for strings that look like errors in the source code and there is little in the way of organization or patterns that I can see. For example, this is a *tiny* sampling of overall errors that I found with a simple `grep` for `FERROR` (I assume this is a file descriptor for *stderr* or equivalent)...

```
"ABORTING due to unsafe pathname from sender: %s\n"
"All source args must come from the same machine.\n"
"Batch file %s open error"
"Daemon option(s) used without --daemon.\n"
"ERROR: Skipping sender remove for changed file: %s\n"
"ERROR: buffer overflow in %s [%s]\n"
"FATAL I/O ERROR: dying to avoid a --delete-%s issue with a pre-3.0.7 receiver.\n"
"Failed to close"
"Hlink node data for %d already has path=%s (%s)\n"
"If arg is a remote file/dir, prefix it with a colon (:).\n"
"Impossible error in external-zlib code (1).\n"
"Integer overflow: attempted 64-bit offset\n"
"Internal hashtable error: illegal key supplied!\n"
"Invalid ID number: %s\n"
"Overflow in read_varint()\n"
"Overflow in read_varlong()\n"
"Unexpected remote arg: %s\n"
"Unknown filter rule: `%s'\n"
"[%s] could not find xattr #%d for %s\n"
"[%s] internal abbrev error on %s (%s, len=%ld)!\n"
"rsync error: %s (code %d) at %s(%d) [%s=%s]\n"
"rsync: did not see server greeting\n"
```

This is just a small subset of the messages that I found with `grep` *and* even that whole set is just a subset of the total overall as a simple grep doesn't catch, for example, messages that aren't on the same line as `FERROR` (and there are plenty of those).

Comment: It looks like I'll have to write things another way.

Comment: Yeah. Frankly, the situation is chaos...not uncommon with code bases that go way back.

Answer (score 0):

Any successful file transfer should have its transfer status in the form of something like `>f..T......` so you could figure out a regex for that and perform a reverse match.

Additionally, rsync's log output format is highly configurable, so you may be able to get what you want by changing that.